# Convert an array of integers into an array of strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have an array:

```
int_array = [11,12]
```

I need to convert it into

```
str_array = ['11','12']
```

I'm new to this technology

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apply method to array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496931/apply-method-to-array-elements)

Answer (score 134):

```
str_array = int_array.map(&:to_s)
```

Comment: i'm still getting the output as 

[11, 12].. i didnt help

Comment: How are you checking the type of your output?

Comment: What is the meaning of the &: ?

Comment: @user1658296 this is a ruby idiom (built-in as of Ruby 1.9, or in Rails for < 1.8) that expands to a block of the form: { |el| el.send(:to_s) }

Answer (score 46):

```
str_array = int_array.collect{|i| i.to_s}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me until I remembered that to do it in place in the array you have to call collect! instead of collect. Then it worked fine.

Comment: shorter to write it this way: 
    `str_array = int_array.map(&:to_s)`

the _"&:"_ means call the "to_s" method on every element of the array.
and "map" is a shorter synonym for "collect"

Answer (score 23):

**array.map(&:to_s)** => array of integers into an array of strings

**array.map(&:to_i)** => array of strings into an array of integers

Answer (score 17):

map and collect functions will work the same here.

```
int_array = [1, 2, 3]

str_array = int_array.map { |i| i.to_s }
=> str_array = ['1', '2', '3']
```

You can acheive this with one line:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array.map! { |i| i.to_s }
```

and you can use a really cool shortcut for proc: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961118/2257912)

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
array.map!(&:to_s)
```

Answer (score 4):

Start up irb

```
irb(main):001:0> int_array = [11,12]
=> [11, 12]
irb(main):002:0> str_array = int_array.collect{|i| i.to_s}
=> ["11", "12"]
```

Your problem is probably somewhere else.  Perhaps a scope confusion?

Answer (score 0):

the shortest option:

```
int_array.map!(&:to_s)
```

Answer (score -3):

## Returns Int

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

## Returns String

```
y = 1,2,3,4,5 # => ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```