# Ruby ampersand colon shortcut

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

In Ruby, I know that if I do:

```
some_objects.each(&:foo)
```

It's the same as

```
some_objects.each { |obj| obj.foo }
```

That is, `&:foo` creates the block `{ |obj| obj.foo }`, turns it into a Proc, and passes it to each.  Why does this work?  Is it just a Ruby special case, or is there reason why this works as it does?

Comment: This is also referred to as [pretzel](http://blog.honeybadger.io/how-ruby-ampersand-colon-works/) [colon](http://technology.customink.com/blog/2015/06/08/ruby-pretzels/) syntax.

Answer (score 507, accepted):

Your question is wrong, so to speak. What's happening here isn't "ampersand and colon", it's "ampersand and object". The colon in this case is for the symbol. So, there's `&` and there's `:foo`.

The `&` calls `to_proc` on the object, and passes it as a block to the method. In Ruby, `to_proc` is implemented on `Symbol`, so that these two calls are equivalent:

```
something {|i| i.foo }
something(&:foo)
```

So, to sum up: `&` calls `to_proc` on the object and passes it as a block to the method, and Ruby implements `to_proc` on `Symbol`.

Comment: More precisely: the ampersand unpacks the `Proc` object so that it gets passed as if it was a literal block. Only if the object is not *already* a `Proc` object, does it call `to_proc`.

Comment: Symbol#to_proc is only native in Ruby > 1.9

Comment: @Steve: No, it's in 1.8.7 as well.

    p RUBY_VERSION
    # => "1.8.7"
    p ["a", "b", "c"].map(&:upcase)
    # => ["A", "B", "C"]

Comment: you're right. it's not in http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Symbol.html for some weird reason though?! :S

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core/ is for 1.8.7, http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7 / is the 1.8.7 equivalent. Here's the entry: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Symbol.html#M000086

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Good to know that it's in Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.

Comment: thanks august. do you know what version of ruby the default docs cover? i.e. /core not /core-1.8.7, /core-1.9. i always thought it was the latest release of 1.8? the way it is is not very helpful!

Comment: It is explained on http://www.ruby-doc.org/. /core is 1.8.6, then there's /core-1.8.7/ and /ruby-1-9/ (yay for no convention).

Comment: @August: Did you mean "ruby-doc.org/core is for 1.8.6"? in your first comment?

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I've *actually* understood what &: was doing, despite using the convention for years.

Comment: Let's say foo has an attribute `name`, is it possible to apply the ampersand on the `foo.name`? e.g. in pseudo-code example: `something(&:foo.name)`.

Comment: So, how does the element, i, get passed to the block? And how does Ruby decide, it's the element of the enumerable, and not the enumerable itself? Is passing the element particular to enumerable objects? Is it applicable for non-enumerables also?

Comment: there's no magic involved. It's completely up to the implementation of `something`, and it calls the provided block as if it was a function.

Answer (score 93):

There's nothing special about the combination of the ampersand and the symbol. Here's an example that (ab)uses the regex:

```
class Regexp
  def to_proc
    ->(str) { self =~ str ; $1 }
  end
end
%w(station nation information).map &/(.*)ion/

=> ["stat", "nat", "informat"]
```

Or integers.

```
class Integer
  def to_proc
    ->(arr) { arr[self] }
  end
end

arr = [[*3..7],[*14..27],[*?a..?z]]
arr.map &4
=> [7, 18, "e"]
```

Who needs `arr.map(&:fifth)` when you have `arr.map &4`?

Comment: Liked this example better than answer marked correct

Comment: Fun to see the `[*3..7]` syntax. I didn't realize you could splat like that!