# Ruby : `&:symbol` syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby/Ruby on Rails ampersand colon shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut)

Seen in [Railscast #167](http://railscasts.com/episodes/167) :

```
def tag_names
    @tag_names || tags.map(&:name).join(' ')
end
```

What is this `&:name` syntax, what does it do ?

I understand what a symbol is, but what other kinds of objects this `&` can be prepended to ?

---

Duplicate question : [Ruby ampersand colon shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut)