# What do you call the &: operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Ruby/Ruby on Rails ampersand colon shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut)
>   [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

I was reading Stackoverflow and stumbled upon the following code

```
array.map(&:to_i)
```

Ok, it's easy to see what this code does but I'd like to know more about `&:` construct which I have never seen before.

Unfortunately all I can think of is "lambda" which it is not. Google tells me that lambda syntax in Ruby is `->->(x,y){ x * y }`

So anyone knows what that mysterious `&:` is and what it can do except calling a single method?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of *six* different questions. And believe me, Ruby hasn't changed *that* much within the last 8 days, so the answers are *probably* going to be the same: http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/99318/, http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/1217088/, http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/1792683/, http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/1961030/, http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/2096975/, http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/2211751/.

Comment: Sure, I know this now. But every new way of wording will help the community and this site. After all, I *did* search before I asked.

Comment: @vava That is a reason *not to delete* the question. Your question should still be closed.

Comment: @Sinan, by closing it, you made it invisible to Google and it will lead to another question like that popping up :)

Comment: @vava http://www.google.com/search?q=What+do+you+call+the+%26%3A+operator+in+Ruby%3F See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230/duplicate-question-etiquette-to-delete-or-not-to-delete

Comment: @Sinan, ok, I stand corrected.

Comment: @AJP That's also how I got here. Every programmer should be using it.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There's a few moving pieces here, but the name for what's going on is the [**`Symbol#to_proc`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) conversion. This is part of Ruby 1.9 and up, and is also available if you use later-ish versions of Rails.

First, in Ruby, `:foo` means "the symbol `foo`", so it's actually two separate operators you're looking at, not one big `&:` operator.

When you say `foo.map(&bar)`, you're telling Ruby, "send a message to the `foo` object to invoke the `map` method, with a block I already defined called `bar`". If `bar` is not already a `Proc` object, Ruby will try to make it one.

Here, we don't actually pass a block, but instead a *symbol* called `bar`. Because we have an implicit `to_proc` conversion available on `Symbol`, Ruby sees that and uses it. It turns out that this conversion looks like this:

```
def to_proc
  proc { |obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args) }
end
```

This makes a `proc` which invokes the method with the same name as the symbol. Putting it all together, using your original example:

```
array.map(&:to_i)
```

This invokes `.map` on array, and for each element in the array, returns the result of calling `to_i` on that element.

Comment: map(&:to_i) is exactly the same as map { |x| x.to_i }. As map requires block and from ruby 1.9 onwards, Symbol to_proc conversion is implicitly available.