# to_yaml file not loading properly in rspec (rails project)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, yaml

I am trying to export my development sqlite3 database into my test database. In order to do this I first exported my model in rails console and saved it to a file.

```
> MyModel.all.to_yaml   # this was saved to mymodels.yml
```

Now when I run rspec it fails while trying to parse mymodels.yml. The error I get is:

> ```
> Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
>  a YAML error occurred parsing /Users/MakeM/MyProject1/spec/fixtures/mymodels.yml.
> ```
>
> Please note that YAML must be
>   consistently indented using spaces.
>   Tabs are not allowed. Please have a
>   look at http://www.yaml.org/faq.html
>        The exact error was:
>          NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for nil:NilClass

Any idea why I am getting this error? One thing I should mention is that the yaml that is output by to_yaml looks a bit strange to me. Here's part of it:

```
--- 
- !ruby/object:MyModel 
  attributes: 
    id: 133
    book: FirstBook
    chapters: 50
    created_at: 2010-10-06 05:03:15.709931
    updated_at: 2010-10-06 05:03:15.709931
    abbr: FB
  attributes_cache: {}

  changed_attributes: {}

  destroyed: false
  marked_for_destruction: false
  new_record: false
  previously_changed: {}

  readonly: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use only data save on your database not all data useless So try to generate your Yaml like that :

```
MyModel.all.map(&:attributes).to_yaml
```

Warning, this technics can explode your RAM if you have a lot of data. Think to generate your haml with limit / offset. or with paginated_each from will_paginate.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly does the .map(&:attributes) do? I tried googling but didn't come up with anything to help me understand.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. I get the same "Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     Bad data for..." error. Though the yaml does look much closer to what it what it should look like.

Comment: map(&:attributes) Call to all model the attributes method and the generate an Array of result

Comment: after doing some research i think this is a bug related to rspec 2 or spork. marking your answer correct since it's what helped me get the correct yaml format. thanks!

Comment: This is very old, but for sake of Google etc... - array.map(&:foo) is a Rubyism explained in the high-rated answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259775/what-do-you-call-the-operator-in-ruby