# What does & mean in this piece of rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

Assume that `Game` is an active record model, what does the & mean in the following code?

```
Games.group_by(&:genre)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [What do you call the &: operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259775/what-do-you-call-the-operator-in-ruby)