# What does this ampersand mean?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)
>   [What do you call the &: operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259775/what-do-you-call-the-operator-in-ruby)

Just watching some railscast and see code like this:

```
[Category, Product, Person].each(&:delete_all)
```

I know that it erases all records for these models, but I can't find out what this `&:delete_all` means.

Comment: This is a duplicate of no less than 20 other questions that have already been asked and answered here on StackOverflow: [Understanding \[ClassOne, ClassTwo\].each\(&:my_method\)](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/99318/), [What does `map(&:name)` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1217088/), [What exactly is `&:capitalize` in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1792683/), [Ruby/Ruby on Rails ampersand colon shortcut](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1961030/), [Ruby : `&:symbol` syntax](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2096975/), …

Comment: … [What is this `&:last` Ruby Construct Called?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2211751/), [What do you call the `&:` operator in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2259775/), [What does `map(&:name)` do in this Ruby code?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2388337/), [What are `:+` and `&+` in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2697024/), [`&:views_count` in `Post.published.collect(&:views_count)`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3888044/), [Ruby Proc Syntax](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4512587/), [How does “`(1..4).inject(&:+)`” work in Ruby](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5003257/), …

Comment: … [Ruby map method syntax question](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5231919/), [What does following statement `&:property` ?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5620411/), [What does the `&` mean in the following ruby syntax?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/5952175/), [Why would one use the unary operator on a property in ruby? i.e `&:first`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6289084/), [how does `Array#map` have parameter to do something like this?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/6716629/), [what does `&:` mean in ruby, is it a block mixed with a symbol?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/9188362/), …

Comment: … [what is the functionality of “`&:`” operator in ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/9429819/), and [What does “`temps.each(&:valid?)`” mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/9926724/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's basically shorthand for this:

```
[Category, Product, Person].each { |e| e.delete_all }
```

That is, it sends `delete_all` to each element of the iterator.

Answer (score 1):

**&:delete_all** basically translates to **|obj| obj.delete_all**. The ampersand calls to_proc on the current object on the loop.

Answer (score 1):

When you put a `Proc` object `pr` with `&` in the last argument position such as in:

```
some_method(&pr)
```

then, a block corresponding to `pr` will be passed to `some_method`. If an object `non_pr` that is not a `Proc` is given like:

```
some_method(&non_pr)
```

then, `non_pr` will be implicitly converted to a `Proc` by `to_proc`.

For example, when `non_pr` is a `Symbol`, then `Symbol#to_proc` will be applied, which happens to be something like this:

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    proc{|obj, *args| obj.send(self, *args)}
  end
end
```

Particularly with `each(&:delete_all)`, the `:delete_all.to_proc` will return the `Proc` object:

```
proc{|obj, *args| obj.delete_all(*args)}
```

so the corresponding block will be passed to `each` like this:

```
each{|obj, *args| obj.delete_all(*args)}
```

Noticing that the arity of a block for `Enumerable#each` is one, this is simplified to:

```
each{|obj| obj.delete_all}
```