# whats does .map(&:chomp) do, exactly?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you call the &: operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259775/what-do-you-call-the-operator-in-ruby)

I see '.map(&:chomp)' all the time

I know what chomp and map do, but I want to know what &: does and I'd like to know why I can't find it on the web after 30 minutes of googling.....

Comment: This is the 22nd duplicate of this question. When are the StackOverflow developers finally going to fix the broken search function so that this doesn't happen anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html), and it turns the symbol into a proc which attempts to invoke the given method on its argument, returning the result.

```
x = :reverse.to_proc

x.call("asdf") # "fdsa", like calling "asdf".reverse
```

In your case, `.map(&:chomp)` is equivalent to `.map { |x| x.chomp }`.

If you can't find it by Googling, it's because you're Googling the wrong thing. It's a well-known Ruby idiom.

Comment: If they [search for `to_proc`](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ruby+to_proc&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) Google spits out all sorts of info.