# Name for this type of abbreviation `map{|x| x.foo}` -> `map(&:foo)`

Tags: ruby

If there is a statement like this `a.map{|x| x.foo}`, I can omit `x` variable like this `map(&:foo)`.

I'm wondering if there is a name for this behavior.
Without name I couldn't looking for similar behavior in other language.

Does somebody know about this?

Comment: This seems like syntax that is specific to Ruby.  In C#, the unabbreviated syntax is called a Lambda Expression, but there's no way to abbreviate it, and a Lambda is something else in Ruby.

Comment: It's a form of type coercion. In this case, it tries to convert the given object to a proc by calling `to_proc` on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's often called "Symbol to Proc". It was originally a hack in Rails, then was incorporated and optimized, in Ruby.

You won't find a similar thing in other languages, unless they also implement Ruby's Symbol type. Symbols aren't the same as constants, but if you imagine a constant that points to a function, maybe a closure in other languages, then you'd be close to its behavior.

"[What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)" is a good discussion about it, along with an example of how it's implemented. Also check out the related posts on the righthand side of that page.

Also, there's "[What do you call the &: operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259775/what-do-you-call-the-operator-in-ruby?lq=1)".

Comment: I was just about to post that link. I love ruby syntactic sugar but it definitely can be confusing sometime. Excellent answer

Comment: If you find that confusing wait until you're debugging dynamically-created methods based on fieldnames in a database, or multi-threaded apps.