# What are :+ and &:+ in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've seen these several times but I can't figure out how to use them. The pickaxe says that these are special shortcuts but I wasn't able to find the syntactical description.

I've seen them in such contexts:

```
[1,2,3].inject(:+)
```

to calculate sum for example.

Comment: Fyi your example is wrong, it should read `[1,2,3].inject(&:+)`

Comment: I double checked, the [1,2,3].inject(:+) definitely works. Why?

Comment: It must be a feature of the `inject` method, then. `inject(:+)` is not Symbol#to_proc, `:+` has no special meaning in the ruby language - it's just a symbol.

Comment: Yes, in ruby 1.8.7+ when no block is given inject uses its first argument as a method name (which is a lot faster than using Symbol#to_proc or a regular block, btw).

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut

Comment: See also [Understanding `[ClassOne, ClassTwo].each(&:my_method)`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/99318/), [What does `map(&:name)` mean in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1217088/), [What exactly is is this in ruby: `&:capitalize`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1792683/), [Ruby/Ruby on Rails ampersand colon shortcut](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/1961030/), [Ruby : `&:symbol` syntax](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2096975/), [What is this `&:last` Ruby Construct Called?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2211751/), [What do you call the `&:` operator in Ruby?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2259775/), ...

Comment: ... [What does `map(&:name)` do in this Ruby code?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2388337/), [`&:views_count` in `Post.published.collect(&:views_count)`](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/3888044/) and [Ruby Proc Syntax](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/4512587/).

Comment: Thank you for this question, this is one of the hardest things to google for I've ever come across, on a par with coalesce in c# (?:).

Comment: @7stud If you don't mind me asking; what it is that you're trying to do with the title? =/

Comment: @Ajedi32, I was trying to change 'Et' looking thing I see to '&', but apparently SO can't parse an ampersand correctly.

Comment: @7stud Weird, the ampersand looks fine for me.

Comment: @Ajedi32, what encoding is your browser set to?  I tried UTF-8 and Latin1, but I still see an 'Et' like thing.  I tried three different browsers, and I see the same thing in all of them.

Comment: @7stud UTF-8 This is what it looks like for me: http://i.imgur.com/4OFmURI.png Maybe it's the fonts you're using? I have no idea.

Comment: @Ajedi32, This is what I see: https://www.flickr.com/gp/54877190@N08/i0p16v  I tried changing the fonts in my browser, but that didn't do anything. Wouldn't the page's CSS control the fonts?

Comment: @7stud I was mostly referring to what fonts are installed on your system. I'm certainly no expert in that area though. Maybe you could find out what UTF-8 character your browser thinks that is, then go from there. Or maybe ask about it on [su] or perhaps even [meta] (depending on whether or not StackOverflow is actually sending your browser the correct character)?

Comment: @Ajedi, The html sent to me by SO uses an html entity for the ampersand: `&amp;`.  I think you are right about it being related to my system's font for an ampersand.  Apparently, an ampersand comes from the latin 'et', and the font I see harks back to those origins.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Let's start with an easier example.
Say we have an array of strings we want to have in caps:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'blah'].map { |e| e.upcase }
# => ['FOO', 'BAR', 'BLAH']
```

Also, you can create so called Proc objects (closures):

```
block = proc { |e| e.upcase }
block.call("foo") # => "FOO"
```

You can pass such a proc to a method with the & syntax:

```
block = proc { |e| e.upcase }
['foo', 'bar', 'blah'].map(&block)
# => ['FOO', 'BAR', 'BLAH']
```

What this does, is call to_proc on block and then calls that for every block:

```
some_object = Object.new
def some_object.to_proc
  proc { |e| e.upcase }
end

['foo', 'bar', 'blah'].map(&some_object)
# => ['FOO', 'BAR', 'BLAH']
```

Now, Rails first added the to_proc method to Symbol, which later has been added to the ruby core library:

```
:whatever.to_proc # => proc { |e| e.whatever }
```

Therefore you can do this:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'blah'].map(&:upcase)
# => ['FOO', 'BAR', 'BLAH']
```

Also, Symbol#to_proc is even smarter, as it actually does the following:

```
:whatever.to_proc # => proc { |obj, *args| obj.send(:whatever, *args) }
```

This means that

```
[1, 2, 3].inject(&:+)
```

equals

```
[1, 2, 3].inject { |a, b| a + b }
```

Comment: `inject` also supports `[1,2,3].inject(:+)` (note you do not need the &)

Comment: in that case, it will check whether an object is passed an call to_proc itself on it.


    def inject(obj, &block)
      block ||= obj.to_proc
      # ...
    end

Comment: That's not ruby's definition of inject. inject does not call to_proc, it uses rb_funcall with the given symbol as the name of the method. See inject_op_i in enum.c.

Comment: Ok, but still the &:+ thing does call to_proc.

Comment: Too much talk about the `&:+` syntax when that was not the question.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD "What are :+ and &:+ in Ruby?" looks like it's asking about `&:+` syntax to me.

Answer (score 3):

inject accepts a symbol as a parameter, this symbol must be the name of a method or operator, which is this case is `:+`

so `[1,2,3].inject(:+)` is passing each value to the method specified by the symbol, hence summing all elements in the array.

source: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html