# In the context of return array.inject(:+) + initial_value, what does ":+" mean?

Tags: ruby

Is it an operator? If it is, how is it being used? Or does it point to something?
I've looked for examples of it's usage in the inject method but all I can really gather is that it somehow acts like { |sum, n| sum + n }.

Answer (score 4):

`:+` is a symbol.

You can see it in IRB:

```
> :+.class
=> Symbol
```

In this context, it actually represents the `+` method that will be invoked instead of a block by `inject`.

You can call it dynamically yourself, like this:

```
> 5.send(:+, 3)
=> 8
```

which is equivalent to:

```
> 5 + 3
=> 8
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that clears it up a  bit. So any thing that starts with ":" is a symbol. So I know that in ruby you can't pass operators as arguments to functions/methods. Though it seems that this is an acting work-around, is that correct?

Comment: @user3827668, You can't pass ANY methods as arguments. Why? Because in ruby when you write a method name like dostuff, ruby executes the method--parentheses are optional.  So, whenever you write a method name, ruby executes the method, making it impossible to pass the method itself.  Therefore, you have to pass a string that is the method name: "do_stuff" or a symbol, which for now you can assume is identical to a string,  :dostuff, and then use the string to execute the method.

Comment: So "+" is not an operator, but rather a method?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this
[How does "(1..4).inject(&:+)" work in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003257/how-does-1-4-inject-work-in-ruby)

and this
[What are :+ and &:+ in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697024/what-are-and-in-ruby)

then you will totally understand :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!