# Why is there no `Enumerable#map(sym)` while there is `Enumerable#inject(sym)`?

Tags: ruby, symbols, proc, enumerable

Why does `Enumerable#map` only support a block while `Enumerable#inject` supports additional types, e.g. symbols?

I expected the following to work

```
["1", "2"].map(:to_i).inject(:+)
```

but only the following works

```
["1", "2"].map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
```

Nevertheless, using `&` for both works too

```
["1", "2"].map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)
```

Which one is the best practice and why?

Comment: Hm, this looks like a duplicate

Comment: Can't find a good post (I remember seeing one here), but the short answer is (IIRC): because that's how it is implemented.

Comment: It would be more consistent if both methods excepted symbols or only blocks, wouldn't it? I thought ruby is super consistent :-)

Comment: Oh but  it _is_ a pinnacle of consistency, compared to PHP. :)

Comment: I will delete my answer if you hate it.

Answer (score 1):

`inject` looks if a block is given, and if not, it uses the symbol argument instead of a block. With `map`, this cannot be done because there is a usage of `map` without a block, which returns an enumerator.

As Sergio comments, it is in principle possible for `map` to look for an argument (rather than or in addition to looking for a block). The problem is due to the particular implementation that C ruby chose. I suspect it is implemented so because it is much faster to check the existence of a block than to check the arity and the class of an argument.

There is no reason you shouldn't use

```
["1", "2"].map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
```

Why not use the convenient symbol argument when it was designed to be used?

Comment: But `map` could be accepting a single argument, a symbol.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That is right, it is in principle possible to do that. The problem is due to the particular implementation that C ruby chose. Cf. sepp2k's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697024/what-are-and-in-ruby). I suspect it is because it is much faster to check for a block than to check for the arity and the class of an argument.

Comment: "There is no reason you shouldn't use" - how about consistency, though, and not having to spend _any_ mental CPU cycles on remembering if this method accepts naked symbols or not? Just use `&:` everythere and you're fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check the [Enumerable docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html)

```
map { |obj| block } → array
map → an_enumerator
```

and

```
inject(initial, sym) → obj
inject(sym) → obj
inject(initial) { |memo, obj| block } → obj
inject { |memo, obj| block } → obj
```

Which one to use from these two

```
["1", "2"].map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
["1", "2"].map(&:to_i).inject(&:+)
```

is up to you, but I quickly checked the performance and `inject` with symbol seems to work faster:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { ([1]*1_000_000).map(&:to_i).inject(:+) }
  x.report { ([1]*1_000_000).map(&:to_i).inject(&:+) }
end

    user     system      total        real
0.120000   0.010000   0.130000 (  0.122907)
0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.146640)
```

Comment: You seem to be answering the second part (which is better), not the first part (why is this so). You should clarify this. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I can't clarify why symbol argument is not implemented for map unfortunately :)

Comment: I meant, clarify that you're answering the latter part :)