# Ruby: Case-Insensitive Array Comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Just found out that this comparison is actually case-sensitive..Anyone know a case-insensitive way of accomplishing the same comparison?

```
CardReferral.all.map(&:email) - CardSignup.all.map(&:email)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is any "direct" way like the minus operator, but if you don't mind getting all your results in lowercase, you can do this:

```
CardReferral.all.map(&:email).map(&:downcase) - CardSignup.all.map(&:email).map(&:downcase)
```

Otherwise you'll have to manually do the comparison using `find_all` or `reject`:

```
signups = CardSignup.all.map(&:email).map(&:downcase)
referrals = CardReferral.all.map(&:email).reject { |e| signups.include?(e.downcase) }
```

I'd suggest that reading a reference of Ruby's standard types might help you come up with code like this.  For example, "Programming Ruby 1.9" has all methods of the [`Enumerable`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) object explained starting on page 487 (`find_all` is on page 489).

Comment: on a side note : What exactly is this "(&:" mean?

Comment: both of these include needless iterations. `map { |c| c.email.downcase }` or `reject { |c| signups.index(c.email.downcase) }` will work just fine

Comment: @Trip: Google for 'ruby ampersand operator'.  It's the Symbol#to_proc method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut

Comment: @thorncp: I think either way is fine.  Most of the performance-sensitive stuff happens in the database anyway, and in terms of readability they're both equally concise.  `reject { |c| signups.index(c.email.downcase) }` by the way doesn't quite do the same thing since it gives you CardReferral objects, not strings.

Comment: `signups.include?` would indicate intent better than `signups.index`.