# Liquid syntax error: Unexpected character during "sort"

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I have this piece of code that executes a sort for this kind of structure:

```
items:
 0:
  date: '2018-01-02'
 1:
  date: '2019-02-02'
 2: 
  date: '2016-03-04'
```

Sort:

```
{% assign sorted = items.sort {|x,y| y[1].date <=> x[1].date} %}
```

Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5710429/2797942

When I run `jekyll serve` it returns `Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 18): Unexpected character { in "{{items.sort {|x,y| y[1].date <=> x[1].date} }}`

I'm quite new to Ruby and Jekyll, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll templates can't accept full Ruby. You can output a context variable, optionally modified by a Liquid filter; invoking `sort` method and passing a Ruby block is out of the question. Try instead:

```
{{ items | sort: "date" | reverse }}
```

Comment: Looks like I can't do this in Jekyll since it's a hash. I have to do this in plugin. Any thoughts on how will approach this in a plugin?

Comment: Then it seems it's a duplicate, the linked question has several techniques mentioned. Note that (AFAIK) GitHub pages (which is like the most common use-case for Jekyll) does not support user-written plugins, so if you're planning to publish on GH pages, a plugin would not help you.