# Why would one use the unary operator on a property in ruby? i.e &:first

Tags: ruby, block, unary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby/Ruby on Rails ampersand colon shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut)

As a habit I try and read a little of someone elses source code regularly and comment on it in a gist. Right now I'm reading through sinatra's base app and came upon an interesting bit of code (this is part of their Request class)

```
def accept
  @env['sinatra.accept'] ||= begin 
    entries = @env['HTTP_ACCEPT'].to_s.split(',') 
    entries.map { |e| accept_entry(e) }.sort_by(&:last).map(&:first)
  end
end
```

The part I don't get is what is &:last and &:first doing?!? It appears as madness!

Comment: closer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the answers in the duplicate questions for the meaning and usage of `&:...`. In this case, `entries` is an array, and there are three methods `map`, `sort_by`, and `map` chained. `sort_by(&:last)` is equivalent to `sort_by{|x| x.last}`. `map(&:first)` is the same as `map{|x| x.first}`. The reason the first `map` does not use `&:...` is because (i) the receiver of `accept_entry` is not `e`,  and (ii) it takes an argument `e`.