# Shortening enumeration code

Tags: ruby, enumeration, ruby-1.9.2

What is a succinct way of accomplishing this in Ruby?
I simply want to wait until all objects are running. This seems too wordy.

```
# arr contains objects that respond to running?
all_running = false
until all_running
    sleep 0.5
    all_running = true
    arr.each{ |obj|
        all_running = all_running and obj.running?
    }

end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sleep 0.5 until arr.all? &:running?
```

Comment: ah, found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut

Comment: It's a shorter way to write `arr.all? {|obj| obj.running?}`.

Comment: It's a `Symbol#to_proc` shorthand, equivalent to `{|i| i.running?}`. This may be Rails specific, just try it in irb :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

`sleep(0.5) until arr.inject(true) { |all_running, obj| all_running and obj.running? }`

Comment: You should replace your code in the context, it only replaces the inner loop but you give the impression that it replaces the whole code.