# Ruby on Rails 3: How to access an attribute of each record in a has_many query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

I wasn't sure how to phrase it in the title, but what I'm trying to do the following. I have 2 models that have the following relationships:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :points
end

class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :campaign
end
```

Now, the Point model has a "locale" attribute and I want to be able to put all the "locales" of every point of a specific campaign into an array, or collection, or whatever without having to do something like

```
locales = Array.new
campaign.points.each do |p|
   locales << p.locale
end
```

I was thinking of something along the lines of `campaign.points.locales`. Is there some nice Rails way of doing this query, or do I just have to iterate over the collection?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:** Also because the relationship is actually a "has_many through" relationship, this method doesn't work, as I get many repeated locales if I try to iterate in that simple way. It sounds like it should be some type of join, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
campaign.points.map {|p| p.locale}
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 7):

I'd do:

```
campaign.points.map(&:locale)
```

Comment: I don't know why I tend to forget suggesting this nice syntax and I use it all the time. Bah :)

Comment: In case somebody wants to know what this means: [Ruby/Ruby on Rails ampersand colon shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut)

Comment: The l33t oozes out of this syntax, melting all pythonistas in its path.

Comment: Adding `.uniq!` eliminates duplicates as well:  `campaign.points.map(&:locale).uniq!`

Answer (score 1):

You could do what those guys said. Put a `.uniq` at the end of them and end up with the correct solution, or;

let me lead you astray with ActiveRecord fun (and possibly failure, since I can't test to see if it works here). But you'll be able to run `campaign.points.locales` just like you wanted.

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :points do
    def locales
      select('DISTINCT(locale)').map(&:locale)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The `.uniq` did the trick for the duplicates. Thank you very much!

Comment: Went away to read the docs in the meantime... Aww I was hoping you'd try the AR solution so I can see if it worked. I promise you time and space benefits (because it only loads the locale column in distinct records from the db)!