# How to pull out attributes from a collection into an array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

If I have a class that looks like below, how to I pull out just the last name from each instance a collection into an array?

```
class Person
  include :Mongoid::Document

  field :first_name
  field :middle_name
  field :last_name
  field :email_address

end

Person.all # What do I do after I have the collection?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return an array from a collection:

```
Person.where(blah).collect(&:last_name)
```

[An explanation of &:object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut)

Answer (score 1):

`Person.all.map(&:last_name)` will do it

Answer (score 0):

Person.where(...search...).only(:last_name)

http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#only