# Is it possible to have a one line each block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a one-line method of writing this each block in Ruby?

```
cats.each do |cat|
   cat.name
end
```

I'm trying to shorten the amount of code in my project.  I'm using Ruby 1.9.2.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this cats.each { |cat| cat.name }

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Yes, you can write:

```
cats.each { |cat| cat.name }
```

Or [simply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut/1961118):

```
cats.each(&:name)
```

Note that `Enumerable#each` returns the same object you are iterating over (here `cats`), so you should only use it if you are performing some kind of side-effect within the block. Most likely, you wanted to get the cat names, in that case use [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) instead:

```
cat_names = cats.map(&:name)
```

Comment: How about if I wanted to do something like this (Which is currently a two liner): User.where(:email => /josh@josh.com/).each do |user| user.destroy
end

Comment: `User.where(:email => /josh@josh.com/).each(&:destroy)`. Here `each` makes sense because destroying is a side-effect. But I'd write: `User.destroy_all(:email => /josh@josh.com/)`

Answer (score 53):

Just remove the line breaks:

```
cats.each do |cat| cat.name end
```

Note, there are two different coding styles when it comes to blocks. One coding style says to *always* use `do`/`end` for blocks which span multiple lines and *always* use `{`/`}` for single-line blocks. If you follow that school, you should write

```
cats.each {|cat| cat.name }
```

The other style is to *always* use `do`/`end` for blocks which are primarily executed for their side-effects and `{`/`}` for blocks which are primarily executed for their return value. Since `each` throws away the return value of the block, it only makes sense to pass a block for its side-effects, so, if you follow that school, you should write it with `do`/`end`.

But as @tokland mentions, the more idiomatic way would be to write

```
cats.each(&:name)
```

Answer (score 17):

Another trick which I use for rails console/irb is to separate commands with ';' e.g.

```
[1,2].each do |e| ; puts e; end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for cat in cats;cat.name;end
```

that should do it too.

Comment: this is very ugly, please look at accepted answer. You should avoid ";" as much as possible for code legibility. Or at least add spaces on line jumps. Also question asks for "block one liner" not for.