# Adding values to a hidden field with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hidden-field, embedded-ruby

I'm working on a way to construct a guest list of an event called a Party. The user_id of each invited guest is stored in a hidden field, separated by spaces.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'guestlist', nil, :class => 'guest_list' %>
```

When a user invites a new guest, the guest's id is added to the field and stored.

I'm trying to figure out a way so that when a User edits an existing party, the id's of the already invited guests show up in the hidden guest_list field.

Is there a way to do this with embedded Ruby? Something along the lines of:

```
<% @party.guests.each do |guest| %>
 Do something here
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (in 2 steps for readability):

```
<% guest_ids = @party.guests.map(&:id).join(",") %>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'guestlist', guest_ids, :class => 'guest_list' %>
```

The first line will call `.id` on each guest and then collect them in an array (like `[1, 4, 12]`) and then the `.join` will put them in to a string where it will use the `","` to separate them.

**EDIT** The `.map(&:id)` is the same as saying:

```
@part.guests.map do |guest|
    guest.id
end
```

But it's condensed in to that `&:id`. The `.id` is obviously the method name we want to call and whose results we want to collect, and the & basically converts that in to a block. You can [read this](http://www.potstuck.com/2011/08/06/ruby-symbols-instead-of-blocks/) for some more information, or perhaps better, [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut).

Comment: No problem! Be sure to mark the answer as the correct answer so others will know what worked for you!

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what does the (&id) syntax signify? Specifically the '&', the rest is pretty straight forward.

Comment: I will add some more to my question to help explain.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Wish I had more than one up-vote to give!