# Ruby on Rails: Finding the sum of a column in a returned search query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to find the sum of a column called `length`, which is simple an integer column full of the number of seconds each record lasted for.

I have a search form setup to query the db for some conditions I have set in the controller:

```
@time_entries = TimeEntry.find(:all, :conditions => [ "(user_id = ?) AND (projecttitle LIKE ?) AND (date BETWEEN ? AND ?)", current_user, '%'+params[:projecttitle]+'%', @startdate, @enddate ])
```

and then I follow that query with my code that doesn't work, trying to sum the `length` column of my returned query...

```
@total_time = @time_entries.sum(:length)
```

and then when I go to render this out in my view with `<%= @total_time %>`, I get this error:

`undefined method '+' for #<TimeEntry:0x007ffdbbd45b78>`

Any ideas? Your help is very appretiated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
@total_time = @time_entries.sum(:length)
```

to

```
@total_time = @time_entries.sum(&:length)
```

Just FYI, if you need only one column to operate use `:select` clause in your query like

```
@time_entries = TimeEntry.find(:all, :select => 'length', 
                  :conditions => [ "(user_id = ?) AND (projecttitle LIKE ?) 
                           AND (date BETWEEN ? AND ?)", current_user, 
                           '%'+params[:projecttitle]+'%', @startdate, @enddate ])
```

And if you need only sum of some column from the table you can use [sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M001704) method like

```
@total_time = TimeEntry.sum(:length, 
                  :conditions => [ "(user_id = ?) AND (projecttitle LIKE ?) 
                           AND (date BETWEEN ? AND ?)", current_user, 
                           '%'+params[:projecttitle]+'%', @startdate, @enddate ])
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much -- may I ask what the `&:` added?

Comment: @briankulp Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut