# why doesn't this work: x.map(&:+"A")

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, ampersand

from what I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut),

```
something {|i| i.foo } 
something(&:foo)
```

are equivalent. So if x = %w(a b c d), why aren't the following equivalent:

```
x.map {|s| s.+ "A"}
x.map {&:+ "A"}
```

?

The first one works as expected (I get ["aA","bA","cA","dA"]), but the second one gives an error no matter what I try.

Comment: You cannot pass argument to those Symbol#to_proc call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Symbol::to_proc` doesn't accept parameters.

You could add a `to_proc` method to `Array`.

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    lambda { |o| o.__send__(*self) }
  end
end

# then use it as below
x.map &[:+, "a"]
```

Comment: That's a very interesting answer, thanks. Any reason why #send is not sufficient and __send__ is needed?

Answer (score 1):

If this worked, you'd have nothing to do as a rubyist. I wrote a whole postfix class built on `#method_missing` to remedy this. Simple dirty solution would be:

```
x = ?a, ?b, ?c

def x.rap( sym, arg )
  map {|e| e.send sym, arg }
end

x.rap :+, "A"
```

Comment: tried this, then x.rap(&:+ "A"), got error.  Ruby 1.9.3p125