# A more elegant way to reject array if it contains only empty strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to sort through a (rows)array of (row)arrays. The (row)arrays contain an arbitrary number of strings. If a (row)array contains only empty strings I want to remove it from the (rows)array.

I'm currently doing this:

```
rows.each do |row|

  row.each_index do |i|

   if row[i].length > 0
    break 
   elsif i == row.count-1
    rows.delete(row)
   end

  end

end
```

But is there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly more concise:

```
rows.reject! { |row| row.all?(&:empty?) }
```

Comment: When calling a method, `&expression` means "evaluate `expression`, call `to_proc` on whatever it returns, and use the value returned by `to_proc` as the block for this method call". `Symbol#to_proc` works like this: `:method_name.to_proc` returns an anonymous function which is just like `{ |x| x.method_name }`.

Comment: So when you are passing a block which looks like `{ |x| x.method }`, you can always compress that down to `&:method`, which should go last in the list of arguments.

Comment: Nice further discussion of & / to_proc here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut

Answer (score 4):

Modifying an array while you iterate though it is not a good idea - you may find your code skips certain elements or does weird stuff. I'd do

```
rows.reject! {|row| row.all? {|row_element| row_element.empty?}}
```

We reject a row if the block `row_element.empty?` evaluates to true for all elements in the row. It's well worth getting familiar with all of the methods in Enumerable, they're very handy for this sort of task.

Comment: It's better to use blank? instead of empty? in case one of elements is nil, blank? will return true, while empty? will error out

Comment: Thanks a lot. For clarity please edit your answer to show that this will return a new array, leaving rows untouched because you used reject instead of reject! Did you do this because using reject! would cause rows to be modified during iteration?

Comment: +1 Since the OP asked for an elegant solution, not to say yours is not, it is perfectly fine, consider this: `rows.reject{ |row| row.all? &:empty? }`

Comment: @iouri blank? is a railsism, although I suppose the question is tagged rails too. 1ndivisible  - didn't realise you were interested in doing it in place - that works too

Comment: Actually I think rows.reject! would be bad in this situation as 'The array is changed instantly every time the block is called and not after the iteration is over' (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject) so this is equivalent to modifying the array during iteration as I was doing. Maybe rows = rows.reject! { ... } would be better?

Comment: Hehe railsism :) I made sure it was tagged with rails

Comment: reject! is fine - it's the entire point of it. `each` isn't expecting for the array to be modified which is why it's bad whereas reject! is the one doing the deleting so is able to keep everything in sync.

Answer (score 4):

when using rails:

```
! rows.any?(&:present?)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `compact.uniq` or `compact`. If your arrays have `nil` values, compact will result in an empty array, so you can check for that like this:

```
row.compact.size == 0
```

if row contains empty strings "" you can check for it like this:

```
row.compact.uniq.first.blank? and row.size == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    rows.select{|row| row.compact.count >0}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here: `rows.all?(&:blank?)`.

Comment: He just wants to reject the array if ALL elements are empty.