# Rails: Better way to create variables for views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, helper

I am totally new to Ruby, and Rails. Currently, I am using helper methods. How can I write the same code as this in my Model 'User' so as to access all these variables from controller and view?

Writting code this way in helper is 100% functional:

```
module HomeHelper

  def init(user_id)
    @friends = Array.new    
    @followers = Array.new

    @user = User.find_by_id(user_id)    #Get User
    @friends = @user.users              #Get all his friends
                                        #
    @statuses = Array.new               #
    @friends.each do |friend|           #
      @statuses += friend.statuses      #Get all statuses for 'a' friend, then loop
    end                                 #
    @statuses += @user.statuses         #
    @statuses = @statuses.sort_by {|status| status.created_at}.reverse!

    @friendsof = Array.new
    @filtered_friendsof = Array.new

    @friends.each do |friend|
      @friendsof += friend.users
    end
    @friendsof.each do |friendof|
      unless (@friends.include?(friendof))
        if @user != friendof
          @filtered_friendsof << friendof
        end
      end
    end
  end

  @filtered_friendsof = @filtered_friendsof.uniq

end
```

Controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user_id=3
  end   
end
```

Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statuses
  has_and_belongs_to_many(:users,
    :join_table => "user_connections",
    :foreign_key => "user1_id",
    :association_foreign_key => "user2_id")
  #has_many :user_connections
end
```

Comment: If i am getting you right.. you want your helper to be accessible across all controllers?

Comment: Is this piece of code supposed to go in 'Helper',as it is, or should go to 'Model'?And if it should go into Model, then how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find(3)
  end 
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statuses
  has_and_belongs_to_many :friends,
    :class_name => 'User'
    :join_table => "user_connections",
    :foreign_key => "user1_id",
    :association_foreign_key => "user2_id"

  def combined_statuses
    (friends.map(&:statuses) + statuses).flatten.
      sort_by {|status| status.created_at}.reverse!
  end
end
```

Now, you don't need your helper method and in your view you can use:

```
@user.friends # instead of @friends
@user.combined_statuses # instead of @statuses
```

I'll let you figure out the rest, but I hope you get the general idea of pushing the logic into the model.

Comment: Thanks!! But Am supposed to use Helpers in this way? I am a beginner. I dont know much about Models. I was pulling in data from database using 'Helpers',but later, I thought that the code I wrote in Helper was supposed to be in Model. ??

Comment: Think of helpers as logic that is only necessary for the views. For example, if you want to display a link if a user is an admin, but not if a user is a regular member. Then you would define that logic in a helper, then in your view call 'edit_link(user)'. Thus, `edit_link` would only return a link if that user was an admin. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Then is it ok to write 'find_mutual_friends(to_find_mutual_friend_of_id)' code in Helper? Thanks, again!

Comment: No, finders should go into the model. You shouldn't really be using ActiveRecord directly in the view helpers. User model should have an instance method called `mutual_friends`.

Answer (score 0):

Most of that logic belongs in the `User` model.  Nothing else needs to be actually doing those computations, and the `User` model has access to all the relevant pieces.  There are additionally several other improvements that can be made.  I'll try to add comments below to indicate these improvements.

Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statuses
  has_and_belongs_to_many :friends,            # now you can just say user.friends
    :class_name => 'User',                     # makes more sense semantically    
    :join_table => "user_connections",
    :foreign_key => "user1_id",
    :association_foreign_key => "user2_id"

  def friends_statuses
    (friends.map(&:statuses).flatten + statuses).sort_by!(&:created_at).reverse
    # Ruby has many great methods for Arrays you should use.
    # You can often avoid instantiating variables like the empty Arrays you have.
  end

  def second_order_friends
    (friends.map(&:friends).flatten.uniq - friends) - [self]
  end
end
```

Controller

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    user = User.find(7) # how do you decide which user you're displaying things for?
                        # this might be better off in 'show' rather than 'index'

    # here you can call all the methods you have for 'User', such as:
    # user.friends, user.statuses, user.friends_statuses, user.second_order_friends

    # to make things accessible in the view, you just need an @variable, e.g.:
    @friends = user.friends
    @latest_statuses = user.friends_statuses.first(10)
  end
```

Comment: Your post really is useful. Where can i learn methods like (friends.map(&:friends).flatten.uniq - friends) - [self] ??

Comment: `map`, `flatten`, `uniq`, `sort_by!`, `reverse`, `-` are all methods of the `Array` class, you can read more [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html) (or just Google "ruby array").  The `&:` is a handy shortcut; [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut) is a good place to start reading about it.