# Using code block as a value in a parent hash

Tags: ruby

I am trying to refactor my code (before it was a bunch of if/else-if statements) using some Ruby magic. However, when I try to use code blocks as my value in a hash, I get the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC :restaurant => { Cuisine.all },
```

This same error repeats for the next line and the line after (`:hotel` and `:attraction`).

What am I doing incorrectly here?

```
def moderation_categories(klass) 
  klass_map = {
    :restaurant => { Cuisine.all },
    :hotel      => { Category.where(place_type: "Hotel") },
    :attraction => { Category.where(place_type: "Attraction") }
  }
  list = []
  klass_map[klass.to_sym].call.each { |c| list << c.name }

  list.sort
end
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but the last three lines of your method could be simplified to one: `klass_map[klass.to_sym].call.map {|c| c.name }.sort`. The `map` method lets you avoid creating and appending that intermediate `list` manually.

Comment: @ScottOlson Awesome, thanks. So much Ruby magic :)

Comment: No problem. Ruby gets even more magic than that, too! Since `{|x| x.method }` turns out to be a common block, there's an even shorter form: `klass_map[klass.to_sym].call.map(&:name).sort`. An explanation for that syntax can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1961030/1535283

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A block does not just stand as a lambda (code block). You must specify it to be a lambda or a Proc.

```
  klass_map = {
    :restaurant => lambda{ Cuisine.all },
    :hotel      => lambda{ Category.where(place_type: "Hotel") },
    :attraction => lambda{ Category.where(place_type: "Attraction") }
  }
```

Comment: Alternatively, `->{...}`. This one is more modern.