# How do i invoke a method chain using map method, in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How would I invoke the block to use `_id.to_s` in ruby?

```
category_ids = categories.map(&:_id.to_s)
```

I am hacking it and doing the following right now:

```
category_ids = []
categories.each do |c|
  category_ids << c.id.to_s
end
```

Comment: The documentation for [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) shows how to use a block. Did you look at it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can pass a block to map and put your expression within the block.  Each member of the enumerable will be yielded in succession to the block.

```
category_ids = categories.map {|c| c._id.to_s }
```

Comment: As of Ruby 2.7, you can use a numbered parameter like so: `categories.map { _1._id.to_s }`

Answer (score 7):

```
category_ids = categories.map(&:_id).map(&:to_s)
```

Test:

```
categories = ["sdkfjs","sdkfjs","drue"]
categories.map(&:object_id).map(&:to_s)
=> ["9576480", "9576300", "9576260"]
```

Comment: If this is critical to performance, you can consider [Enumerator::Lazy](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Enumerator/Lazy.html) as [this comment in a related Q/A pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76719614/how-do-you-efficiently-chain-array-methods-in-ruby?noredirect=1#comment135258089_76719614)

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to chain methods, you can override the Symbol#to_proc

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc
    to_s.to_proc
  end
end

class String
  def to_proc
    split("\.").to_proc
  end
end

class Array
  def to_proc
    proc{ |x| inject(x){ |a,y| a.send(y) } }
  end
end

strings_arr = ["AbcDef", "GhiJkl", "MnoPqr"]
strings_arr.map(&:"underscore.upcase")
#=> ["ABC_DEF", "GHI_JKL", "MNO_PQR"]

strings_arr.map(&"underscore.upcase")
#=> ["ABC_DEF", "GHI_JKL", "MNO_PQR"]

strings_arr.map(&["underscore", "upcase"])
#=> ["ABC_DEF", "GHI_JKL", "MNO_PQR"]
```

---

```
category_ids = categories.map(&"id.to_s")
```

[Ruby ampersand colon shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut)

[IRB](https://repl.it/repls/CharmingEvenBookmark)