# How to get self.read_attribute to work with aggregates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have:

```
class Vehicle << ActiveRecord::Base

  def odometer
    metric ? self.read_attribute(:odometer).miles.to.kilometers : self.read_attribute(:odometer)
  end

end
```

When `metric = true` and I do `vehicle.odometer` it works, I get kilometers.

But when I call an aggregate `vehicles.sum(:odometer)` it does not work, as if the method odometer is not being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your `vehicles` is an ActiveRelation object and calling sum on it will calculate the sum using sql query(not using the method you have defined)

Query generated will be

```
select sum(vehicles.odometer) from vehicles where ...
```

If you want your method to be called, do the following

```
 vehicles.sum(&:odometer)
```

Comment: Your solution worked. Do you happen to know where can I find documentation on using the '&'?

Comment: It does not seem to be working with `vehicles.maximum(&:speed)`

Comment: `vehicles.sum(&:odometer)` is another way of writing `vehicles.sum{|v| v.odometer}`. You can find some explanation here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut

Comment: `average` and `maximum` doesn't work because they are not defined in Enumerable