# Simple sort in Ruby without using sort method (note that the list to be sorted is "strings")

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

Given

```
30.02 -88.87 10.58 -99.22 107.33
```

to sort without the `sort` method. I have spent a few hours on this without any success.

```
def simple_sort(list)      # I have to start with this method

 list = list.split(' ')  # I understand i need to .split to get arrays
```

Because they're floats I need a way to make them floats with `to_f` method `.each(&:to_f)` I saw this before but I'm not sure I understand the "`:`". I thought colon made objects symbols so anyone please explain `(&:to_f)` to me?

```
 sorted_list = []        #thought of creating an empty array to store the new list
```

This is the part that gets tricky! Where do I go from here?

I want to go through each item in the array, find the smallest number and add it to the `sorted_list`

```
def sort_list(list)
  list = list.split(' ').map(&:to_f)
  sort = []
  while sort.length < list.length
    sort << list.min
    list.delete(list.min)
  end
  sort = sort.join(' ')
  return sort
end
```

instead of using the <=>, what would make this code work?

Comment: I have read algorithms for bubble sort, insertion sort, I kinda understand the concept, but lacking the creativity for the method.

Comment: `each(&:to_f)` does nothing useful. It's equivalent to `each { |i| i.to_f }` which simply converts the values to floating point numbers, then discards the results. If you want to save the result, use `map`.

Comment: There are two completely different questions here.

Comment: interesting, thanks @tadman

Comment: so when i run this code it gives me the first 3 items in the array as it becomes equal to the length n the list. and stops.

Answer (score 3):

Open IRB and try things:

```
>> foo = '30.02 -88.87 10.58 -99.22 107.33'
"30.02 -88.87 10.58 -99.22 107.33"
>> foo.split
[
    [0] "30.02",
    [1] "-88.87",
    [2] "10.58",
    [3] "-99.22",
    [4] "107.33"
]
```

So `split` breaks the string on whitespace, so far so good.

```
>> foo.split.each(&:to_f)
[
    [0] "30.02",
    [1] "-88.87",
    [2] "10.58",
    [3] "-99.22",
    [4] "107.33"
]
```

Hmm... the values didn't change so `each` might not be doing what you think it does. Trying `map` instead:

```
>> foo.split.map(&:to_f)
[
    [0] 30.02,
    [1] -88.87,
    [2] 10.58,
    [3] -99.22,
    [4] 107.33
]
```

Once the values are converted to floats then it becomes easy to sort them.

Note: You can use the `<=>` operator (AKA "spaceship") to tell you whether one is less-than, equal, or greater-than another, which makes it easy to know when you should swap them. For instance:

```
0 <=> 1 # => -1
1 <=> 1 # => 0
2 <=> 1 # => 1
```

You should read the documentation for the [Comparable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Comparable.html) module, which makes it really easy to add additional functionally to a class by defining the `<=>(other)` method.

`map` allows us to modify/transform an array's elements, whereas `each` only iterates over them. You *can* use `each` to mess with the elements, but it's not generally what you want to do since `map!` makes it easier to transform things.

Regarding `&:to_f`. This was a hack on Ruby's symbols a while back, that was added to Rails. It turned out to be so useful that it was pulled into Ruby itself. It's called a "symbol to proc" and is discussed in "[Ruby ampersand colon shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut)".

Comment: ah I'm trying to post it like its code and as you can see I'm having a hard time there too

Comment: i tried that but I'm getting the first 3 and the rest isn't being << inside sort.

Comment: yea the proc symbol makes sense now. Thanks.. the Tin Man

Comment: One of the best written explanations I have seen in a while.