# Get records from multiple tables ordered by shared column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm new to rails and i don't know how to do this simple operation :

i have ,

```
class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles
   has_many :questions
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :section
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :section
end
```

and i want to get all articles and questions under a certain section but sorted together by shared column 'updated_at' .

i tried including and joining them but failed to order them together .

Comment: Once you get them together out of the db into an array you can use sort the array on the updated_at or you could use group by to group by the date depending on how you plan to display the array matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by finding the section that you wish to work with.  For example, you could find a particular section by ID (12 in this case):

```
section = Section.find(12)
```

You can then access the articles and questions that belong to that section and combine the results with the `+` operator:

```
articles_and_questions = section.articles + section.questions
```

The `articles_and_questions` variable is of type [`ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html).  Because the `@target`s of `section.articles` and `section.questions` are both `Array`s of objects, you can call any method from the [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) class on `articles_and_questions`.  In this case, you can use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) which comes from the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html) module included in `Array`:

```
sorted_articles_and_questions = articles_and_questions.sort_by &:updated_at
```

If you want to know why there's an ampersand in `&:updated_at`, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961118/137744).

Comment: thank you for ur help , however i still have a problem when i add up the articles and questions together how do i know which are articles or questions and access them ? , i tried doing like `- @sorted_posts.each |post|` then `= post.title` (they have a common column title) but its gives an error of : undefined method !

Comment: i solved it by defining a method inside each model named "type" that returns the name of the table , then setting conditions on types to know which type of post im dealing with .. i dont know if this is the optimal solution  .

Comment: I'm glad that helped!  I'm afraid I can't reproduce your problem.  I was able to do something like `@sorted_posts.each do |post| puts @sorted_posts.title end` in the rails console.  If you do need to find out the type of each post, you can use Ruby's `instance_of?` method (`@sorted_posts.first.instance_of? Question`).

Answer (score 0):

Once the result is in a single array you can do:

`@sorted = @records.sort_by     &:updated_at`