# How to do math operation with columns on grouped rows

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

I have Event model with following attributes (I quoted only problem related attributes), this model is filled periodically by API call, calling external service (Google Calendar):

```
colorid: number # (0-11)
event_start: datetime
event_end: datetime
```

I need to count duration of grouped events, grouped by colorid. I have Event instance method to calculate single event duration:

```
def event_duration
  ((event_end.to_datetime - event_start.to_datetime) * 24 * 60 ).to_i
end
```

Now, I need to do something like this:

```
event =  Event.group(:colorid).sum(event_duration)
```

But this doesnot work for me, as long as I get error that event_duration column doesnot exists. My idea is to add one more attribute to Event model "event_duration", and count and update this attribute during Event record creation, in this case I would have column called "event_duration", and I might be ale to use sum on this attribute. But I am not sure this is good and "system solution", as long as I would like to have model data reflecting "raw" received data from API call, and do all math and statistics on the top of model data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event_duration is instance method (not column name). error was raised because Event.sum only calculates the sum of certain column

on your case, I think it would be easier to use enumerable methods

```
duration_by_color_id = {}
grouped_events = Event.all.group_by(&:colorid)
grouped_events.each do |colorid, events|
  duration_by_color_id[colorid] = events.collect(&:event_duration).sum
end
```

Source :

- [Enumerable's group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)
- [Enumerable's collect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect)

Comment: Thanx a lot, it works auto-magically. Problem is, I am Rails & Ruby beginner and I do not understand this code, event it is just a few lines. I have to check especially that "&:something" magic, and why is used "group_by" and not just "group".

Comment: @DavidLister : please check this out : [ampersand colon shorcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut)

Comment: Thanx for reply, I spent some time with study. Let me summarize it if I got it correctly:
`duration_by_color_id = {}`
Initialize new hash
`grouped_events = Event.all.group_by(&:colorid)`
Get multidim. array with all events, which are grouped by colorid DB column, because this block is executed for each object and i just call colorid, which gives back value of row.
`grouped_events.each do |colorid, events|`
Start iterate array. For each colorid key, i have array of events.
`duration_by_color_id[colorid] = events.collect(&:event_duration).sum`
Gives me array with sum values for each object.