# Ruby save variable if it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm parsing an XML file with Nokogiri and I only want to save the variable if a value exists for it in the XML.  Right now, I'm having it rescued with a `nil`, which is generating the wrong results for me.  So, how can I set my statement to only save if both of these have actual values (not nil)?

```html
port.xpath("service").each do |service|
            product = service.at_xpath("@product").value rescue nil
            version = service.at_xpath("@version").value rescue nil
```

Currently, when the file is parsed both of the values could be nil, which then matches to everything!  Instead, I really need my parser to just pass over the values if it can't find a `product` & `version` match.

For instance, let's say the XML says that the service is `product vFTP` and `version 2.2.1`.  This is good, because it matches correctly (vFTP 2.2.1).

However, if `version nil`, I now have a problem because it will match with all versions of vFTP now.

An `if statement` to check for `defined?` seems logical, but for some reason that doesn't seem right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple ways. On the next line:

```
next unless [product, version].all?(&:present?)
```

or

```
next if [product, version].any?(&:nil?)
```

Comment: Awesome!  What exactly does `(&:present?)` mean?

Comment: [`present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F) means `!blank?`.

Comment: What about the `&:`?

Comment: Here's [a description of the `&:foo` notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut).