# ruby passing &:key as an argument to map instead of a block

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I wrote the following code:

```
def report_view_classes
  [
    Hourdiff,
    AverageTimeForFirstReferrals,
    CountZipCodeByUserids,
    FirstRentForUsers,
  ]
end

def load_views
  report_view_classes.each do |report_view_class|
    report_view_class.create
  end
```

but rubocop gives me following warning:

```
C: Pass &:create as an argument to each instead of a block.
  report_view_classes.each do |report_view_class
```

I am confused what to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby ampersand colon shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut)

Comment: In such cases it's always best to refer to the source: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/0.26.1/RuboCop/Cop/Style/SymbolProc.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a shorthand for simple blocks.

```
["apple", "pear", "grape"].map { |fruit| fruit.upcase }

# This does the same thing with less code:

["apple", "pear", "grape"].map(&:upcase)
```