# Ruby get strings from array which contain substring

Tags: ruby

I've got an array of strings. A few of the strings in this array contain a certain substring I'm looking for. I want to get an array of those strings containing the substring.

I would hope to do it like this:

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
o.select(&:include?("c"))
```

But that gives me this error:

```
(repl):2: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
o.select(&:include?("c"))
                        ^
```

Comment: You need to use a block `o.select{|e| e.include?('c')}`

Comment: `['abc', 'def', 'ghi'].grep(/c/)` would work as well.

Comment: You are trying to use what is called "pretzel colon" syntax, but like @SebastiánPalma said, it doesn't accept arguments. Check these two docs for more about pretzel colon syntax: http://technology.customink.com/blog/2015/06/08/ruby-pretzels/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was called "pretzel colon syntax", I spent way too long trying to google "ruby ampersand meaning" and variants thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there, you cannot pass parameter in `&:`. You can do something like:

```
o.select{ |e| e.include? 'c' }
```

Answer (score 5):

**You can use the `&`-shorthand here. It's rather irrational (don't do this), but possible.**

If you do manage to find an object and a method so you can make checks in your `select` like so:

```
o.select { |e| some_object.some_method(e) }
```

(the important part is that `some_object` and `some_method` need to be the same in all iterations)

...then you can use `Object#method` to get a block like that. It returns something that implements `to_proc` (a requirement for `&`-shorthand) and that proc, when called, calls `some_method` on `some_object`, forwarding its arguments to it. Kinda like:

```
o.m(a, b, c) # <=> o.method(:m).to_proc.call(a, b, c)
```

Here's how you use this with the `&`-shorthand:

```
collection.select(&some_object.method(:some_method))
```

In this particular case, `/c/` and its method `=~` do the job:

```
["abc", "def", "ghi"].select(&/c/.method(:=~))
```

Kinda verbose, readability is relatively bad.
Once again, don't do this here. But the trick can be helpful in other situations, particularly where the proc is passed in from the outside.

---

**Note:** you may have heard of this shorthand syntax in a pre-release of Ruby 2.7, which was, unfortunately, [reverted](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/fb6a489a) and **didn't make it to 2.7**:

```
["abc", "def", "ghi"].select(&/c/.:=~)
```

Comment: Pretty nifty! I've not seen that before.

Comment: @Stefan nah, its use tends to be longer than the usual definition because of the lengthy `.method`. So I can't come up with any use case for it in golf. Except... when competing for the least number of tokens maybe.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson on pretzel colon syntax. I ended up using: `o.select do |str|; str.include?("c"); end` (except with newlines instead of semicolons).

Comment: @Jones "pretzel colon" refers to `&` (pretzel) with a **symbol** (colon+word). This answer was supposed to show that you can use other values (than symbols) too ("pretzel damn-huge-method-chain", LOL). It's quite rare though. And it makes sense to tick the answer you used in the end. I don't mind those 15 rep, and having a tick on an answer that almost starts with "don't do this" feels odd.

Answer (score 5):

If your array was a file `lines.txt`

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Then you would select the lines containing `c` with the `grep` command-line utility:

```
$ grep c lines.txt
abc
```

Ruby has adopted this as [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep). You can pass a regular expression as the pattern and it returns the strings matching this pattern:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi'].grep(/c/)
#=> ["abc"]
```

More specifically, the result array contains all elements for which `pattern === element` is true:

```
/c/ === 'abc' #=> true
/c/ === 'def' #=> false
/c/ === 'ghi' #=> false
```

Comment: Another example (though not applicable here) is `["a", 1, {b: 2}, [3,4], {c: 5}].grep(Hash) #=> [{b: 2}, {c 5}]`, because `Hash === {b: 2}` is equivalent to `{b: 2}.instance_of?(Hash) #=> true`.