# What is `-@` in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I ran into this code snippet in a codeWars solution.

```
def invert(list)
  list.map(&:-@)
end
```

I've never seen the `@` before in ruby. It looks like it lets you specify an operation on the iterator in a `&:` anonymous function call.

I'm trying to work on my ruby terminology. What is the `@` called in Ruby and when was it introduced?

Comment: It *looks* like `:-` is the binary `a - b` operator and `:-@` is the unary `-a` operator.

Comment: see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

Comment: Do you know what `list.map(&:foo)` does?

Comment: ampersand colon would call the meth foo as a proc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut

Comment: You can check with any number as `23.methods => [:to_s, :inspect, :-@, ..` It is mandatory for list to have all objects which supports method  '-@'

Comment: @xander-miller: So, if `list.map(&:foo)` calls a method named `foo` on every element, then what does `list.map(&:@-)` do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can use it

```
[1,2].map(&:-@) #=> [-1, -2]
```

Comment: I found my answer in the comments on codeWars. `-@` is actually a method on integer. If you call `1.methods` you can see it. The method inverts the value of the integer.

Comment: yes that was clearly explained in the link I commented on your question but this clearly illustrates a use case IMHO.

Comment: @xander-miller It is not specific to Integer, it is merely a syntax for defining unary operators, not just `-`. Think of a vector class, you would likely define unary negation, and they are not integers. It is just another method name, with some different syntax on how to clarify it from a binary operator.