# Why the lambdas hangs in 'each' iterator? Ruby 2.6.5

Tags: ruby, lambda

Ruby 2.6.5

Have a method to interact array of hashes and filter them. User can put array of students and as many filters as he wants. If I use one filter, everything is going fine. But if I put second filter, the program is hangs in irb console and nothing is going on. Memory limit exceeded. What am I doing wrong?

```
def filter(students, *filters)
  return students if filters.empty?

  result = []
  filters.each do |filter|
    students.each { |student| result << student if filter.call(student) }
    students = result
  end
  result
end
```

```
students = [
  { name: 'Thomas Edison', gpa: 3.45 },
  { name: 'Grace Hopper', gpa: 3.99 },
  { name: 'Leonardo DaVinci', gpa: 2.78 }
]

filter_1 = ->(record) { record[:gpa] > 3.0 }
filter_2 = ->(record) { record[:gpa] < 3.9 }
```

If I will call the method only with filter_1 or filter_2 (`filter(students, filter_2)`), everything is going fine, but when I put there one more argument (`filter(students, filter_1, filter_2)`), the programs is hanging.

**What I did already**

If I will delete only one string (`students = result`) code will work. And fast return the result:

```
filter(students, honor_roll, filter_2)
 => [{:name=>"Thomas Edison", :gpa=>3.45}, {:name=>"Grace Hopper", :gpa=>3.99}, {:name=>"Thomas Edison", :gpa=>3.45}, {:name=>"Leonardo DaVinci", :gpa=>2.78}]
```

But I need exactly implement filters one by one. I tried to modificate arrays of results after implementing each iteration, but there is the same problem. Also I tried to not use `students` array:

```
def filter(students, *filters)
  # Write your code here
  return students if filters.empty?

  result = []
  filters.each_with_index do |filter, index|
    array = index.zero? ? students : result
    array.each { |student| result << student if filter.call(student) }
  end
  result
end
```

But result is the same.

How can I fix this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you aware that you can just write `students.select(&filter_1).select(&filter_2)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue lies in the following lines:

```
result = []
filters.each do |filter|
  students.each { |student| result << student if filter.call(student) }
  students = result
end
```

With one filter everything works since `students` and `results` are different arrays. However at the end of the first iteration you set `students = result` which means that the `student` and `result` variable refer to the same array.

So what's the problem? The second time you enter the loop you add students to `result` using `result << student` (if the filter results to a truthy value). Since both `result` and `students` refer to the same array you implicitly add them to the `students` array, which you are currently iterating.

Let me demonstrates what happens with a simple example:

```
# Assume we have the students collection: [1] and the filter call will
# always result in a truthy value.
students = [1]
students.each { |student| students << student if true }
```

Like you can see above by adding elements to the collection you're iterating you end up in an endless loop.

So, what do you need to do to fix this? Without changing your current code too mutch simply moving the `result = []` inside the `filters.each` loop will fix the issue. This will create a brand new array for each iteration.

```
filters.each do |filter|
  result = []
  students.each { |student| result << student if filter.call(student) }
  students = result
end
students # you can't return `result` any more, since it's not in scope
```

---

However, Ruby offers many iteration methods that can help you simplify this whole method. Something like this also does the trick:

```
def filter(students, *filters)
  students.select do |student|
    filters.all? { |filter| filter.call(student) }
  end
end
```

Here I use the [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-select) iteration method to select the students that match some criteria. I then use the [`all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) iteration method to check if the student matches all filters.

Another one that comes to mind is:

```
def filter(students, *filters)
  filters.reduce(students) { |students, filter| students.select(&filter) }
end
```

This uses [`reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) to reduce the `filters` collection to a single value (a students collection). While doing this use [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-select) to select the students that match the current filter (shrinking the `students` collection each iteration).

Comment: @RuslanValeev If you don't fully understand the `select(&filter)` syntax check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut/1961118) question.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the statement `students = result`. This makes `student` point to the same memory location as `result` -- the are the **SAME** object from this point forward. So now when you call `result << ...` that's the *same thing* as calling `students << ...`, and therefore the loop never ends because you are constantly appending to the thing you're looping over.

To see this:

```
students = [1]
result = students
results << 1
students
# => [1,2]
```

I'd suggest using ruby-core's `select` (also called `filter`, in fact) method (or the inverse `reject`):

```
results = students
filters.each do |filter|
  results = results.select(&filter)
end
```

If you don't know `&` syntax, that's basically equivalent to

```
results = students
filters.each do |filter|
  results = results.select{|x| filter.call(x)}
end
```

This way, you're starting with the full list and dump the matching students into a new array for each filter.

Or do them all at once:

```
students.select{|x| filters.all?{|f| f.call(x) } }
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is on a loop is because students and result are referencing the same region of memory when you call `students = result`, so every time you insert a `student` element in `result` the `students` array increase its size, making the `each` loop endless, you should use `students = result.clone` to prevent this.
But it's not the only problem, your algorithm is not correct, you should just use this:

```
def filter(students, *filters)
  return students if filters.empty?
  result = students.clone
  filters.each do |filter|
    result.select! { |student| filter.call(student) }
  end
  result
end
```