# Ruby - problems with user input to integer array

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

I am trying to accept input of two integers, separated by a space: `3 5` and save that into an integer array. I do this 3 times, but I am having trouble converting this from string to integers. Here is my loop:

```
for i in 1..3
    puts "What is point " + i.to_s + " ?"    # asks for input
    s.push gets.split(" ")
end
```

Then, I want to have

```
if s[1][0] - s[0][0] = 0
    blah blah blah
end
```

The array `s` currently looks like

```
------------
| "1"  "2" |
| "3"  "4" |
| "5"  "6" |
------------
```

I want it to look like

```
--------
| 1  2 |
| 3  4 |
| 5  6 |
--------
```

I have tried `gets.split(" ").map { |s| s.to_i }` and `gets.split(" ").collect{|i| i.to_i}` but I realize I should just ask someone here.

I have just started learning Ruby, so if you don't mind a short explanation with the solution, i would really appreciate it  :)

Thanks!

Note: This is pretty much the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781054/convert-an-array-of-integers-into-an-array-of-strings-in-ruby), and I did try to use `.collect` and `.map` following the loop, which still did not work.

Comment: What *is* being stored in `s`? If you are using an older version of ruby, you should try `<<` instead of `push`, ex: `s << gets.split(' ')`. Your code as it is works as you want it to on my computer.

Comment: Currently stored is the array I want, but stored as a strings. I'm using Ruby 1.9.1. ( I also edited original question)

Comment: I am using 1.9.1 too, and your exact code (with the `gets.split(" ").map { |s| s.to_i }` instead of just `gets.split(" ")` is producing arrays of integers.

Comment: I got it working now, thank you. That was very strange. I think before I may have had `map { |i| i.to_i }`, would that have caused it to fail for some reason? I was previously getting `undefined method 'to_i' for ["1", "2"]:Array`

Comment: @phoffer: I don't think so, maybe.

Comment: With that error, it was probably because you tacked `map` on after the for loop, instead of after `split`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, sorry, I just saw the mistake. I can't believe I missed that.

In your `if` statement, you are using `=` instead of `==`. `=` *assigns* things, and `==` *compares* things. A full working program could look like this:

```
s = []
for i in 1..3
    puts "What is point " + i.to_s + " ?"    # asks for input
    s.push gets.split(" ").map {|x| x.to_i }
end
if s[1][0] - s[0][0] == 0 # notice the '=='.
    puts 'It worked!'
end
```

Comment: I did fix that after I asked the question, I realized how stupid of me. I had some `puts` in between which were showing it failing though, so the actual error was separate from that. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer looks good to me.  You might replace s.push with s << (more Rubyish) and there is no need for split's argument.  Though I'm a newbie, I think most Rubyiests would write:

s << gets.split.map {|x| x.to_i}

Also, you could replace

puts "What is point " + i.to_s + " ?"

with

puts "What is point #{i} ?"

Comment: What does << mean? I didn't know I could drop the argument on split. And then it makes sense that I can drop the .chomp too

Comment: << is the append operator.  You could write, for example,
dog = '' << 'ca' << 'nin' << 'e' => "canine"
Note if a = 'ca' and b = 'nine', c = a << b => "canine",
but also a => "canine", which may not be what you want.
 
<< works similarly with arrays:
q = [] << 'quick' << 'brown' << 'fox' => ["quick", "brown", "fox"]

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks, that is really good to know! If that isn't what I want, I would just use `+` instead. Good to know these little things.