# Apply method to each elements in array/enumerable

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

This is my array:

```
array = [:one,:two,:three]
```

I want to apply `to_s` method to all of my array elements to get `array = ['one','two','three']`.

How can I do this (converting each element of the enumerable to something else)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert an array of integers into an array of strings in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781054/convert-an-array-of-integers-into-an-array-of-strings-in-ruby)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This will work:

```
array.map!(&:to_s)
```

Comment: It works in Ruby 1.8.7 for sure. I use it in my projects all over.

Comment: Symbol#to_proc wasn't available in 1.8.6, but is available in 1.8.7: http://apidock.com/ruby/Symbol/to_proc . I know this from personal experience as well, as I don't use Rails or its libraries.

Comment: I figure it's worth noting that `collect` and `collect!` are aliases for `map` and `map!`.

Comment: what's the `!` for?

Comment: @user1492534 `!` is part of the method name, no magic, but it's used to tell you it defines the changed value to `self` instead of just returning the changed value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/612196/540447

Answer (score 20):

You can use [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249) or [`map!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000250) respectively, the first will return a new list, the second will modify the list in-place:

```
>> array = [:one,:two,:three]
=> [:one, :two, :three]

>> array.map{ |x| x.to_s }
=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick and detailed answer!

Answer (score 17):

It's worth noting that if you have an array of objects you want to pass individually into a method with a different caller, like this:

```
# erb
<% strings = %w{ cat dog mouse rabbit } %>
<% strings.each do |string| %>
  <%= t string %>
<% end %>
```

You can use the `method` method combined with block expansion behavior to simplify:

```
<%= strings.map(&method(:t)).join(' ') %>
```

If you're not familiar, what `method` does is encapsulates the method associated with the symbol passed to it in a Proc and returns it. The ampersand expands this Proc into a block, which gets passed to `map` quite nicely. The return of `map` is an array, and we probably want to format it a little more nicely, hence the `join`.

The caveat is that, like with `Symbol#to_proc`, you cannot pass arguments to the helper method.

Answer (score 10):

- `array.map!(&:to_s)` modifies the original array to `['one','two','three']`
- `array.map(&:to_s)` returns the array `['one','two','three']`.

Comment: @sawa: Actually, that's not true. Ruby-On-Rails is actually a programming language, with more questions asked about it than about Ruby. But just like Perl, CLU and SmallTalk, Ruby has incorporated the best bits of it into its language. ;) http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: @Andrew Okay. Thanks. I removed my comment right before you gave some.

Comment: For those wondering what I was humorously replying to, @sawa basically asked if the answerer knew that Ruby is a language, and that Rails is a framework that runs on Ruby, because @sawa thought that Symbol#to_proc was Rails-only in 1.8.7.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: no, Ruby on Rails is not a programming language.