# How to convert a array of strings to an array of symbols?

Tags: ruby

I want to convert the elements of the string array below to symbols, and output them

```
strings = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
```

look at what I'm doing:

```
strings.each { |x| puts x.to_sym }
```

No success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/800122/best-way-to-convert-strings-to-symbols-in-hash

Comment: @Abe: That's for keys of a hash. This is for array elements.

Comment: @Abe That is not a dup, it's for hashes. (edit: icktoofay beat me to it :P)

Comment: @icktofay I see, but it would be easy to convert them, right?

Comment: @Abe That doesn't mean it's a duplicate.... Also, not really. Do you know Ruby?

Comment: @Abe: Maybe, but you'd have a cleaner answer if you just started out trying to do it with an array.

Comment: @Doorknob Not really I confess :P  But I'll keep the comment because it got an up vote

Comment: It should work. Not clear what you mean by not success.

Comment: For those saying the link recommended by @Abe isn't applicable, it is. The keys of a hash *ARE* an array. `{'a'=>1}.keys.class => Array`. The problem is you have to know how to identify where that array is being massaged from strings into a symbol.

Comment: @theTinMan EXACTLY!!!

Comment: @Abe probably this is more of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496931/apply-method-to-array-elements

Comment: @lulalala perhaps, but that's more of a global area rather than a local idea.

Comment: Try #map. `strings.map(&:to_sym)`

Answer (score 60):

Use `map` rather than `each`:

```
>> strings.map { |x| x.to_sym }
=> [:HTML, :CSS, :JavaScript, :Python, :Ruby]
```

For Ruby 1.8.7 and later or with ActiveSupport included, you can use this syntax:

```
>> strings.map &:to_sym
=> [:HTML, :CSS, :JavaScript, :Python, :Ruby]
```

The reason your `each` method appears to not work is that calling `puts` with a symbol outputs the string representation of the symbol (that is, without the `:`). Additionally, you're just looping through and outputting things; you're not actually constructing a new array.

Answer (score 34):

Clean one-liner:

```
%w(HTML CSS JavaScript Python Ruby).map(&:to_sym)
```

`&` tells argument should be treated as a block, i.e. build up array and apply `to_sym` to each element.

Comment: Your answer is the cleanest of all, also I Benchmarked it and checked its performance on different kind of arrays.

I wasn't sure if it was better to give a new answer based on yours or just edit this one.

Answer (score 10):

I'd do something like

```
strings.map! &:to_sym
```

Answer (score 4):

[icktoofay already gave the correct answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16502890/676874)

On additional remark: With

```
strings.map { |x| x.to_sym }
```

you get a new array, the original array is unchanged.

To use it, you can assign it to another variable:

```
string2 = strings.map { |x| x.to_sym }
```

If you want to modify string, you can use `map!`:

```
strings.map! { |x| x.to_sym }
```

Answer (score 2):

@icktoofay has the correct answer, but just to help you better understand the `each` method, here is how you can do the same thing using `each`:

```
strings = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
symbols = [] # an empty array to hold our symbols
strings.each { |s| symbols << s.to_sym }
```

Answer (score 1):

@cb24's answer is generally the most appropiate, I wanted to compare that solution with another one

```
strings.collect {|x| x.to_sym }
```

I did some benchmarks and @cb24's answer works best in most cases, when there are some more elements in the array, but if it happens to be a very tiny array, the collect method works a little faster.

I publish here the code and the results, this is my real first benchmark so if I got something wrong some feedback would be appreciated. I did it on both String -> Symbol and Symbol -> String

```
n = 1000000 

a = [:a,:b,:c,:d,:e,:f,:g,:h,:i].freeze #A "long" array of symbols

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times { a.map(&:to_s)} }
  x.report { n.times { a.collect{|x| x.to_s}} }
end  

       user     system      total        real
   2.040000   0.010000   2.050000 (  2.056784)
   2.100000   0.010000   2.110000 (  2.118546)


b = [:a, :b].freeze  #Small array

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times { b.map(&:to_s)} }
  x.report { n.times { b.collect{|x| x.to_s}} }
end  


       user     system      total        real
   0.610000   0.000000   0.610000 (  0.622231)
   0.530000   0.010000   0.540000 (  0.536087)



w = %w(a b).freeze  #Again, a small array, now of Strings
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times { w.map(&:to_sym)} }
  x.report { n.times { w.collect{|x| x.to_sym}} }
end 

       user     system      total        real
   0.510000   0.000000   0.510000 (  0.519337)
   0.440000   0.010000   0.450000 (  0.447990)



y = %w(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q).freeze #And a pretty long one
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report { n.times { y.map(&:to_sym)} }
  x.report { n.times { y.collect{|x| x.to_sym}} }
end 

       user     system      total        real
   2.870000   0.030000   2.900000 (  2.928830)
   3.240000   0.030000   3.270000 (  3.371295)
```

The inflection points I didn't calculate but it is quite interesting, I read somewhere that some improvements where made with short arrays, since most of them are just a couple of elements long.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go the gem route, [finishing_moves](https://github.com/forgecrafted/finishing_moves) has an [`Array#to_sym_strict`](https://github.com/forgecrafted/finishing_moves/wiki/Array#arrayto_sym_strict) method that does exactly what you're looking for:

```
strings = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby"]
strings.to_sym_strict
# => [:HTML, :CSS, :JavaScript, :Python, :Ruby]
```

There's also a [`#to_sym_loose`](https://github.com/forgecrafted/finishing_moves/wiki/Array#arrayto_sym_loose) to handle arrays of mixed type:

```
strings = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Ruby", 1, /a regex/, {a: :hash}]
strings.to_sym_loose
# => [:HTML, :CSS, :JavaScript, :Python, :Ruby, 1, /a regex/, {a: :hash}]
# no exceptions thrown
```

Answer (score 0):

Or can be done as follows:

```
strings.each do |s|  
symbols.push(s.to_sym)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of completeness you can also make use of the `%i` string literal since at least Ruby 2.0.0 to start off with an array of symbols.

```rb
%i[HTML CSS JavaScript Python Ruby]
# => [:HTML, :CSS, :JavaScript, :Python, :Ruby]
```