# Iterate without an explicit block idiom

Tags: ruby

In my code, I have an array of `ActiveRecord::Base` objects, and to save them, for example, I would do something like this:

```
obj_list = [ar_obj1, ar_obj2, ar_obj3]
obj_list.each { |obj| obj.save! }
```

It would perhaps be nice and DRY to say instead:

```
obj_list.each.save!
```

However, I cannot see how to do this.

Comment: Try to use [search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496931/apply-method-to-each-elements-in-array-enumerable)

Comment: It might be a good idea to wrap the `save!` calls in a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Symbol#to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) shortcut here. But it's still a block, only hidden.

```
obj_list.each(&:save!)
```

Comment: Thanks - that is just what I was looking for! I think it is more readable in that form for casual readers.