# finding median in Ruby

Tags: ruby

input: A list of numbers from the keyboard.
output: The median of the input numbers

I need the whole code

```
def median(array)
array.sort!
  if (array.length % 2==1 )
     return array[array.length/2.0]
  else
     return (array[array.length/2] + array[(array.length/2)-1])/2.0
  end
end
```

How can I enter list from keyboard and the find the median?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with your `median` method? If not, your question should be simply: “How to get array of numbers from keyboard“.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want numbers separated by spaced on a single input line (i.e. 1 5 56 6 75), add the following to your script:

```
input_array = gets.chomp.split(" ")
```

Then pass `input_array` to your median method

Update: Note that input_array will be an array of strings, so you'll need to convert values to integers. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781054/convert-an-array-of-integers-into-an-array-of-strings-in-ruby) a good example on doing so.